# Rails: Appending and Interpolating Code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, append, interpolation

I have a lightbox in which I want to render a Rails partial, like so:

```
var data = "render :conversations => new";
$('#lightbox').append('#{escape_javascript(data)');
```

Unfortunately, this results in the text "render :conversations => new" appearing in the lightbox, rather than the actual rendering. I assume this is because I'm appending the partial rather than rendering it at runtime. I've followed the advice on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416460/render-a-partial-from-jquery-and-haml), but to little success. It recommends I add a "!=" in front of the append line like so:

```
!= "$('#lightbox').append('#{escape_javascript(data)');"
```

This throws a syntax error because of the "!=". Perhaps I'm using this symbol incorrectly, but I can't find any information about it on Google. How might I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do:

```
$('#lightbox').append('#{escape_javascript(render :conversations => new)');
```

But I don't really understand how your code could result in appending the text "render :conversations => new". `var data = "render :conversations => new";` looks like JavaScript and `escape_javascript(data)` is server side ruby so it could not know about `data`. I notice also that the the `#{` has no ending `}`. Is this really the exact code you tested?

Comment: All excellent points. Unfortunately, even with corrected syntax the code doesn't interpolate, instead rendering: "#{escape_javascript(render :conversations => new)}"

Comment: Ah ok but was it "#{escape_javascript(data)}" before then? is this in a static js file or a rails erb template etc? if a template i think you should use the erb syntax `<%= ... %>` instead of ruby string interpolation `#{ ... }`

Comment: Unfortunately, it's in a static js file--and a fairly hefty one at that. (It handles all aspects of the lightbox.) I do have it in the assets pipeline, but I'm assuming that won't help with patching in the erb syntax.

Comment: Ah, I think this was the tip I needed! I changed the js file to js.erb, and it seems to be working. I'm getting some other errors, but at least it seems to be interpolating now.

Comment: What is the error? not really sure how template rendering will work together with the assets pipeline. Update: looks like bad news: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1370

Comment: I think you need to render the partial in a view instead, maybe pass the rendered text as argument to some JavaScript function?

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. I'm researching wasy to get the javascript out of the assets pipeline, short of cutting and pasting it directly into the view. I'll update you once I find an answer.

Comment: You could do something like this: in the static js file `function show_lightbox(html) { blablabla... append(html); }` and then in the view you render it like this: `<a href="" onClick="show_lightbox(<%= escape_javascript(...) %>)">show</a>` etc

Comment: Clever trick! It works, though I wonder how well it performs on slower machines, as it's passing a pretty big chunk of code. I was also able to get [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3438707/1255372) to work.

Comment: Cool. I don't i will be that heavy, i would guess the heaviest part will be to parse the html code each time the lightbox i shown... but as always, just try if it really is slow :)